# Explain how this python while loop returns the reverse order of elements in a list

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Could someone explain to me how this python loop outputs the reverse order of elements in a list? This was part of a school assignment and I can't quite comprehend how this works.

I know this is a more difficult way of obtaining the reverse order of a list, but we were not allowed to use the reverse function and I could not seem to get list splicing to pass the autograder.

```
def reverse_list(stuff):
    '''Function that reverses the order of elements in a list'''
    i = 0
    n = len(stuff)-1
    while i<n:
        temp = stuff[i]
        stuff[i] = stuff[n]
        stuff[n] = temp
        i+=1
        n-=1
#test
stuff = [1,2,3,4]
reverse_list(stuff)
print(list) #Output [4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: `temp` isn't necessary; `stuff[i], stuff[n] = stuff[n], stuff[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using better names, and a print you may better understand

```
def reverse_list(stuff):
    begin = 0
    end = len(stuff) - 1
    while begin < end:
        temp = stuff[begin]
        stuff[begin] = stuff[end]
        stuff[end] = temp
        begin += 1
        end -= 1
        print(stuff)
```

For input `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` you'll see

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1] # swap 1 and 9
[9, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1] # swap 2 and 8
[9, 8, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1] # swap 3 and 7
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] # swap 4 and 6
```

The way is, getting two indexes

- one starting at the beginning and incrementing : `begin`
- one startting at the end and decrementing : `end`

And each time on swap then using a third variable `temp`, and 2 by 2 you're going to swap all, until you reach the middle